# Nameerror: name 'result' is not defined. Speech to Speech transalator

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from google_trans_new import google_translator
import pyttsx3
import pyaudio
recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
engine=pyttsx3.init()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Clearing the background noises...')
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
    print ('Waiting for your message')
    audio=recognizer.listen(source,timeout=1)
    print('Done recording')
try:
    print('Recognizing')
    result=recognizer.recognize_google(audio,language='en')
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

#translation function
def trans():
    langinput=input('Type the language you want to translate to:')
    translator=google_translator()
    translate_text=translator.translate(str(result),lang_tgt=str(langinput))
    print(translate_text)
    engine.say(str(translate_text))
    engine.runAndWait()
trans()
```

this is my code and i keep getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'result' is not defined
  File "/home/ikbentfisser/vscode/translator.py", line 24, in trans
    translate_text=translator.translate(str(result),lang_tgt=str(langinput))
  File "/home/ikbentfisser/vscode/translator.py", line 28, in <module>
    trans()
NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

i have tried changing my code multiple time sbut i failed im new to python so i dont know alot about it

Comment: your try block has thrown an exception and as a consequence the variable `result` has not been defined. Your except clause should make sure that the program can continue executing safely (eg: defining result with a dummy value) or abort the program in case a failure of the try block is critical

Comment: be careful with your indentation.  as it currently appears in the question it is quite possible you have indentation issue (can't tell if the try block should be out dented the way it is.

Comment: What output did *print(ex)* give you?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).